# Is this a D bug? (cannot access private template argument)

Tags: compiler-errors, d, private

`handled_record.d`:

```
module handled_record;

template CObjects(alias destructor) {
    void f() {
        destructor();
    }
}
```

`world.d`:

```
module world;

import handled_record;

private void free() { }

alias objects = CObjects!(free);
```

Compiling:

```
$ dmd -c *.d
handled_record.d(5): Error: function world.free is not accessible from module handled_record
world.d(7): Error: template instance `handled_record.CObjects!(free)` error instantiating
```

The error disappears if I remove `private` keyword.

Is it a compiler bug? (In my understanding the alias symbol passed to a template should be accessible by the template because it is explicitly passed to the template, even if it is private.)

Comment: I don't know if that is a bug or not (I'd have to look more into it), but there is a trivial workaround: pass a function that wraps it. Like `CObjects!( () { free(); });` that should compile without trouble.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Defining a wrapper obviates the usage `private`, as it effectively allows to call the private function

Comment: Right... but isn't that what you want? Then the CObjects thing can access it. And note the wrapper function I defined there is inline to the template definition so it isn't accessible from anywhere else.